# Cannot upgrade Scientific Linux to version 6.5

Tags: yum, repository, scientific-linux

I have been trying to figure out a way to get my Scientific Linux box to upgrade to version 6.5. It's currently 6.4 and everytime I perform a yum update I get an error message (see below!). Can anyone tell me what needs to be done to get past this issue?

**Some Stats:**

- Scientific Linux 32 bit - running on Lenovo Thinkpad 430 4GB RAM - 320GB HDD
- No extras or addons at all, just plain install via CD/DVD which was done from around Nov. 2012

error message:

```
[triton@localhost ~]$ su
Password: 
[root@localhost triton]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * elrepo: mirror.symnds.com
 * elrepo-extras: mirror.symnds.com
 * elrepo-kernel: mirror.symnds.com
 * epel: mirrors.ptd.net
 * epel-source: mirror.cogentco.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.rit.edu
 * rpmforge-extras: mirror.rit.edu
 * sl: ftp.scientificlinux.org
 * sl-addons: ftp.scientificlinux.org
 * sl-security: ftp.scientificlinux.org
http://dl.atrpms.net/src/el6.4-i386/atrpms/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: atrpms-source. Please verify its path and try again
[root@localhost triton]#
```

Answer (score 4):

As of right now, December 6th, 2013, 16:00 UTC, Scientific Linux hasn't released version 6.5. Redhat, CentOS and Oracle **have** released their 6.5 updates, but SL has **not**. Historically I'm under the impression they take a bit longer than CentOS and Oracle to vet the RHEL changes and port them over to their release.

https://www.scientificlinux.org/

Answer (score 1):

@SuperMagic's answer looks to be the correct one but I'll offer this tip for situations such as the one you're encountering.

When you get these messages when running `yum update`:

```
http://dl.atrpms.net/src/el6.4-i386/atrpms/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: atrpms-source. Please verify its path and try again
```

The messages is pretty clearly telling you that the URL "http://dl.atrpms.net/src/el6.4-i386/atrpms/stable/repodata/repomd.xml" is 404. Additionally the repository "atrpms-source" isn't accessible.

You could disable that one repo prior to running the update like so:

```
$ yum update --disablerepo=atrpms-source
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you both! Turns out it WAS the URL that was "404". There *is* no release of 6.5 yet for Scientific Linux, guess I'll just wait it out! Thanks again for the replies!